# JQuery-Javascript looping issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I'm working on a banner for a website and I need it to loop through the images. My problem is that it plays through the images once and then stops. I've tried everything that I can think of with no luck. I'm sure this is simpler than I'm making it, but some help would be greatly appreciated. The latest version is below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Variables required by script
    var currentimage;

    // Load Gallery XML file
    $.ajax({
        url: 'banner.xml',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'xml',
        error: function(){
            alert('Error loading XML document');
        },
        success: function(xmlData){
            // do something with xml
            setupImages(xmlData);
        }
    });


    // Display images
    function setupImages(xmlData) {
        // read xml and use it to populate page 
        //get first image
        currentimage = $(xmlData).find("image:first");

        // Fade in image after countdown
        var t = setTimeout(function(){showNewImage()}, 1000);
    }


    // Display the image, caption, rating and label 
    function showNewImage() {
        var image = $(currentimage).find("path").text();
        var caption = $(currentimage).find("caption").text();

        $("#imagelabel").removeClass("active");
        // Fade out current image and fade in new image
        $("#bannerimgholder").animate({opacity:0},500, 
            function(){
                $(this).css({"backgroundImage":"url("+image+")"}).animate({opacity:1},1000, 
                function(){
                    $("#imagelabel").addClass("active");
                });
            });
        // Add caption
        $("#imagelabel").text(caption); 

        var to = setTimeout(function(){getNextImage()}, 5000);
    }

    function getNextImage(){
        var tmp = $(currentimage).next();                                               
        if ($(tmp).find("path").text()=="") {
            currentimage = $(xmlData).find("image:first");
        } else {
            currentimage = tmp;
        }
        showNewImage();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that I came up with.

First I added an element to the end of my xml file with just a 'path' attribute of "last".

Next, I add the following variable to save the path name of the first element:

```
var imagepathtext;
```

Then, in the setupImages(xmlData) function I added the following:

```
imagepathtext = $(currentimage).find("path").text();
```

Lastly, I changed the getNextImage() function from

```
function getNextImage(){
    var tmp = $(currentimage).next();                                               
    if ($(tmp).find("path").text()=="") {
        currentimage = $(xmlData).find("image:first");
    } else {
        currentimage = tmp;
    }
    showNewImage();
}
```

to

```
function getNextImage(){
                var tmp = $(currentimage).next();                                               
                if ($(tmp).find("path").text()=="last") {
                    while ($(tmp).find("path").text()!=firstimagepath)
                    {
                        var tmp1 = $(tmp).prev();
                        tmp = tmp1;
                    }
                    currentimage = tmp;
                } else {
                    currentimage = tmp;
                }               
                showNewImage();
            }
```

And just like magic it loops correctly now!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using `next()`, which will return nothing once you reach the last image.

You need to use a different test to close the loop, for example:

```
tmp.length==0
```

Note that tmp is already a jQuery object, so you don't need to wrap it in $().

[This page](http://www.mattvanandel.com/999/jquery-nextorfirst-function-guarantees-a-selection/) offers an example of nextOrFirst() function that does what you want.

Comment: I looked that over, but I guess I'm still not understanding what I need to do.

Comment: The first step would be to replace ($(tmp).find("path").text()=="") in your code with (tmp.length==0)

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't change the output. It still cycles to the last image in the xml file and stops.

Comment: right, there seems to be another issue: your xmlData variable is local, you need to pass it to the function or make it global.